# How can I insert rich text content programmatically in Microsoft office power point using java script?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint-addins

I am trying to insert Rich Text Content in power point using a add in I am developing. I went through Microsoft Office documentation, couldn't get any solution. For Word add in there is method exist, but for Power Point no such method available.

[text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.coerciontype?view=common-js-preview)
Documentation says html can't be insert for Power Point.

Looking for any other methods/approach. What I am trying to do is copy text from a RichEditBox in my application onto a PowerPoint slide and maintain font-color, format, etc. I am able to successfully bring the text into PowerPoint. I just can't bring in the formatting (such as font-color) with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.